# Load menuitems from feature services

Tags: angular

I am working on a large project using Angular (2). We will have all our features in separate modules, and all features must provide their own menuitems to a core navigation service/component. Features will get the menuitems from a HttpAPI.

How can i, at bootstrap, initialize all services and fetch menuitems from them? I must also ask the featureservices to update the links when a user has logged in, since the authorization will give different menuitems.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks / Peter

Comment: You can try this approach. Create NavMenuComponent. The template: `<nav><menu-item-1></menu-item-1> <menu-item-2></menu-item-2> ... </nav>`. In AppComponent put your selector `<nav-menu></nav-Menu>`. Finally, you can create a service which will inform different menus that the user is login : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Can you explain how i should get the navitems for the lazy loaded modules?

Comment: You can try this way. Create a method in your component (for example item1 component) `getMenuItems(): void {
    this.SomeService
        .getItems().then(Items => this.items = items)
        ;
  }`. Then you execute your method on component initialization : `ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMenuItems();}`

Comment: I dont want my core services to care about the feature services. I need the opposite DI direction. Services calling the navigatorservice to report what they have.